# URL be truncated if it contains '#' in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url

Suppose making a http get request as following:

```
var url = "https://ss1.bdstatic.com/k4oTfnSm1A5BphGlnYG/newmusic/happy.png";
var img = new Image();
img.src = url + '?hello=world|a=1|href=#feedback';
```

in chrome(47.0), the request url is https://ss1.bdstatic.com/k4oTfnSm1A5BphGlnYG/newmusic/happy.png?hello=world|a=1|href=,

> lost #feedback

in Firefox(42), the request url is https://ss1.bdstatic.com/k4oTfnSm1A5BphGlnYG/newmusic/happy.png?hello=world|a=1|href=#feedback.

Why chrome truncate  the url?

Comment: Simply urlencode the parameters, # is used for anchoring within a page

Comment: But Firefox works fine.

Comment: its a non-conforming url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is a valid URL, but it does not mean what you're thinking it does.

Your URL if correctly parsed is the following:

```
scheme = https
authority = ss1.bdstatic.com
path = k4oTfnSm1A5BphGlnYG/newmusic/happy.png
Query = hello=world|a=1|href=
fragment = feedback
```

If you want your Query to be `hello=world|a=1|href=#feedback`, you must encode the `#`, otherwise it will be understood as the end of the Query and Start of the Fragment.

Encoding it you URL will look like:

[https://ss1.bdstatic.com/k4oTfnSm1A5BphGlnYG/newmusic/happy.png?hello=world|a=1|href=%23feedback](https://ss1.bdstatic.com/k4oTfnSm1A5BphGlnYG/newmusic/happy.png?hello=world%7Ca=1%7Chref=%23feedback)

If you want to encode it in Javascript use the `encodeURIComponent`.

```
var url = "https://ss1.bdstatic.com/k4oTfnSm1A5BphGlnYG/newmusic/happy.png";
var img = new Image();
img.src = url + '?hello=world|a=1|href=' + encodeURIComponent('#feedback');
```

The difference is occuring probably because the [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.2) does not say URLs can have `fragment` in HTTP requests, so Chrome decided they cannot have and Firefox takes it as part of the Query part.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to expand on my comment, very well written!